how to set a keyboard shortcut to open/close the AI chat panel in Firefox?
I'd like to toggle the AI panel using the ctrl-shift-A combo, but I don't know how to configure
Anybody had luck with such a thing using any extension or script?

There is no shortcut to do that, and I doubt that there is an extension/script that can do that either.
You can vote on the Idea for them to add this on the Mozilla "New Ideas and Feature Requests" site https://connect.mozilla.org/t5/ideas/add-shortcut-for-ai-feature/idi-p/65290
